# redirect_to in private methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an action that is calling a private method. If an error occurs in this private method  *redirect_to* is called. The issue is that it gets to *redirect_to* and according to the logs it is redirecting but doesn't on the client end and results in an error.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try changing the private method temporary to public, but I think it's unlikely that it will help.

Try installing the Firefox plugin `httpfox` and have a look at the raw bytes the browser receives.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely no problem with calling redirect_to from a private method, your problem is something else.